# How to setup samba conf file for read only group and read/write for a certain user in a share

Tags: fedora, permissions, samba

I need to create a share in Linux (Fedora) and one group must have only read rights and one certain user can read/write. The rest has no access.

this is part of my configuration file. How can I set the read/write and only read rights?

```
[share2]
    path = /srv/share2
    valid users = simone +sales
    browsable = yes
    writeable = yes
    public = no
    read only = no
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the man page for `smb.conf` would be very useful. (You'll need to skim it several times before diving in deeply.)

You have a couple of mistakes in your share definition.

- Lists are items separated by commas.

  ```
      valid users = simone, +sales
  ```
- You haven't specified a read list or a write list

  ```
      read list = +sales
      write list = simone
  ```